# Charts js and laravel: Render chart after passing in json data

Tags: laravel, charts, laravel-5.3, chart.js

I seem to be struggling rendering a chart even though I have passed all my data correctly as json_encode. What could i be doing wrong. The below code gives me error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>   on line  data: {{json_encode($revenue)}},

//Controller

```
public function chartjs()
{    
    $revenue = Invoice::all()->pluck('amount')->tojson();
    return view('home')
        ->with('revenue',json_encode($revenue));
}
```

//blade view

```
<script>
(function() {
     var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
      var year = ['2013','2014','2015', '2016'];
     var chart = {
        labels: year,
        datasets: [{
            data: @{{json_encode($revenue)}},
            fillColor : "#94646D",
            strokeColor : "#A37079",
            pointColor : "#BC808B",
            showTooltips: true,
            responsive: false
        }]
     };

     new Chart(ctx).Line(chart);
})();
```

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <canvas id="canvas" height="280" width="600"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are doing `json_encode()` twice. In the controller and in the scripts. Call `json_encode()` in the controller and then in the script do

```
data: {{ $revenue }},
```

Or

```
data: <?php echo $revenue; ?>,
```

`$revenue` is undefined because you pass it a session variable using `with()`. Instead return it to your view like this:

```
$revenue = Invoice::all()->pluck('amount')->tojson();
return view('home', compact('revenue')); //'revenue' will match $revenue
```

Comment: I have implemented data: <?php echo $revenue; ?>, as above but now getting 'revenue' as undefined variable...

Comment: Oh yes, because you set `$revenue` as a session variable. Check my updates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the chart thing but you are encoding your data 3 times!!!

```
public function chartjs()
{    
    $revenue = Invoice::all()->pluck('amount')->toJson();
    // $revenue is already a json string
    return view('home')
        ->with('revenue',$revenue); // you don't need this json_encode
}
```

Also in your view you don't need the json_encode. You also might need to put the json string inside quotation.

```
 data: @'{{$revenue}}',
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're calling json_encode more than once. The tojson() must be enough.

Your return could be like this

```
return view('home', [ 'revenue' => $revenue ]);
```

And then print it on javascript like this:

```
data: {!! $revenue !!}
```

Also check if the data structure printed in your HTML source code is equivalent to the one required by the chart library.